# SQL Server: Can you combine/map 2 columns into 1 via stored procedure in SELECT statement itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

Can you combine / map 2 columns into 1 via a stored procedure in a `SELECT` statement itself?

Something akin to:

```
SELECT 
    (EXEC @TIMESPAN = #CREATE_24HR_TIMESPAN, [open], [closed]) AS TIMESPAN 
FROM 
    #TEMP
```

To set the scene, I've got a table with a couple of columns with from time and to time with data resembling '7am' '8am'.

I've written a stored procedure to convert the strings to a 24hr clock format with range 0..23.

I call this twice and multiply the *from time* by 100 and add the *to time*, so, I'd end up with 708.

I want this because It's going to make it easy to create a Pivot Table later...

I want to know is there a way to include the EXEC inline with a SELECT statement?

I'm familiar with cursors as a solution, but was wondering if the SELECT is plausible.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do what you want.  Stored procedures cannot be used in queries -- with the major exception being storing values into a table using `insert`.

Instead of a stored procedure, create a user-defined scalar function (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine)).  From your description of the stored procedure, it should be easy to turn it into a function.

I mean, even that seems hardly necessary.  You could just do:

```
select datepart(hour, [open]) * 100 + datepart(hour, [closed])
```

(assuming they are stored as `time`).  If they are strings:

```
select datepart(hour, convert(time, [open] )) * 100 + datepart(hour, convert(time, [closed]))
```

Comment: I had a sneaky suspicion that may be the case.. Don't think REXSTER allows functions. And this is why I wanted stored procedures...

Comment: I was trying to answer someone else's post on stack overflow, and their starting temp table left a lot to be desired. Was gonna try and map it to something sensible. So columns start off as strings..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the variable types:  Tested with Varchar, DateTime and Time

```
Declare @open varchar(max),  @closed varchar(max)
--Declare @open DateTime,  @closed DateTime
--Declare @open  Time,  @closed  Time
Select @open = '7AM'
, @closed = '8AM'

select Substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),cast(@open as datetime), 8),1,2) 
        + Substring (CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),cast(@Closed as datetime), 8),1,2)
```

As a helpful asside, I have this snippet store for whenever I to dance with Date / Time Formats:

```
    WITH lv0 AS (SELECT 0 g UNION ALL SELECT 0)
        ,lv1 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) -- 4
        ,lv2 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b) -- 16
        ,lv3 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b) -- 256
        ,Tally (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM lv3)
    SELECT  CAST( n AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' - ' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),cast('1/1/11 7AM' as datetime), n) xZample
    , 'CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@YouMindIfWeDanceWitYourDates, '+CAST(n AS VARCHAR(25))+')' AS  _________________________tehcode____________________________
    FROM Tally
    WHERE (n< 200) AND (n%100 IN (0,20,21,120,121,126,127,130,131) OR n%100 <= 14)
    ORDER BY n;
```